# Is it possible to zoom vertical axis on Flutter Charts?

Tags: flutter, charts, zooming, yaxis

I am trying to familiarize with charts in Flutter, using github.com/google/charts package.

I want to make a chart (bar, line, scatter or any other.. [this, for example](https://github.com/google/charts/blob/c0e20095d9fec59b0a65b338402b204644d12e18/docs/flutter/example/behaviors/sliding_viewport_on_selection.md)) where I can zoom and pan not only the x-axis, but also the vertical y-axis (abscissa).

The zoom in x-axis is working adding the behavior `behaviors: [new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),]`  :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      behaviors: [new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
      ],
      domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(
          viewport: new charts.OrdinalViewport('2018', 4)),
    );
  }
```

the x-axis zoom is not centered, as asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223438), but it's ok to me.

A first step would be disable the auto-fit of the vertical axis is adjusting the range between 0 and the max value of the data that appear in that moment in the chart.

Any idea how to enable zoom gesture on the y-axis or at least disable the auto-fit of y-axis (fix the range of y-axis)?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite similar to what you did in domainAxis.
You could just add an axisSpec to the primaryMeasureAxis (y-axis).
like this,

```
primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
      viewport: charts.NumericExtents(4, 8)),
```

But this doesn't work properly in bar charts.
As of my experience, the bar chart will go below the x-axis. It hasn't be fixed yet.
It works well with line chart though.